# How can I make divs inside of a column equal-height?

Tags: html, css

[Problem: Divs not aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcVMY.png):

[image]

The problem is when the text wraps, for example `Money back guarantee`, pushes the div out of alignment with `30 days`.
I am trying to use the `grid` approach to first define `two columns`.

My code:

```css
.inline-features {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<div class="inline-features">
    <div class="feature">
        <div class="price col-1-item">
            <span>
                Price
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="money-back col-1-item">
            <span>
                Money back guarantee
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="number-of-lessons col-1-item">
            <span>
                Number of lessons
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="number-of-users col-1-item">
            <span>
               Number of users
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="country col-1-item">
            <span>
               Based in country
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="support col-1-item">
            <span>
                Support
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="video-lessons col-1-item">
            <span>
                Video lessons
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="downloadable-files col-1-item">
            <span>Downloadable files</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="feature-item">
        <div class="price-item col-2-item">
            <span>   From xx to xx </span>
        </div>
        <div class="money-back-item col-2-item">
            <span>   30 days </span>
        </div>
        <div class="number-of-lessons-item col-2-item">
            <span>   300+ </span>
        </div>
        <div class="number-of-users-item col-2-item">
            <span>   35k + </span>
        </div>
        <div class="country-item col-2-item">
            <span>  UK</span>
        </div>
        <div class="support-item col-2-item">
            <span>   24/7 live chat support </span>
        </div>
        <div class="video-lessons-item col-2-item">
            <span>   Yes </span>
        </div>
        <div class="downloadable-files-item col-2-item">
            <span>   Yes </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you haven't added your grid-item sizes?

Comment: If it is a table, then use a `<table>`. Semantic HTML ftw!

Comment: Also, that looks like either a [`<table>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) or a list (whether [`<ol>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol), [`<ul>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul), or [`<dl>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl)) would be perfectly appropriate for the information you're trying to convey. Tables are not something to inherently avoid just because they were abused (by necessity) for layout at one point, they're still perfectly valid for presentation of data.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML structure is not correct. Try this way.

> To do this type of design, you can use table. This will be better way for manage.

```css
.inline-features{
  width: 250px;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.col-1-item,
.col-2-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline-features">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1-item">
      <span> Price </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2-item">
      <span> From xx to xx </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1-item">
      <span> Money back guarantee </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2-item">
      <span> 30 days </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1-item">
      <span> Number of lessons </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2-item">
      <span> 300+ </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.inline-features {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  font-size: 4rem;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.col-1-item,
.col-2-item {
  padding: 1rem;
  height:140px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline-features">
  <div class="feature">
    <div class="price col-1-item">
      <span>Price</span>
    </div>
    <div class="money-back col-1-item">
      <span>Money back guarantee</span>
    </div>
    <div class="number-of-lessons col-1-item">
      <span>Number of lessons</span>
    </div>
    <div class="number-of-users col-1-item">
      <span>Number of users</span>
    </div>
    <div class="country col-1-item">
      <span>Based in country</span>
    </div>
    <div class="support col-1-item">
      <span>Support</span>
    </div>
    <div class="video-lessons col-1-item">
      <span>Video lessons</span>
    </div>
    <div class="downloadable-files col-1-item">
      <span>Downloadable files</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="feature-item">
    <div class="price-item col-2-item">
      <span>From xx to xx</span>
    </div>
    <div class="money-back-item col-2-item">
      <span>30 days</span>
    </div>
    <div class="number-of-lessons-item col-2-item">
      <span>300+</span>
    </div>
    <div class="number-of-users-item col-2-item">
      <span>35k +</span>
    </div>
    <div class="country-item col-2-item">
      <span>UK</span>
    </div>
    <div class="support-item col-2-item">
      <span>24/7 live chat support </span>
    </div>
    <div class="video-lessons-item col-2-item">
      <span>Yes</span>
    </div>
    <div class="downloadable-files-item col-2-item">
      <span>Yes</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use  instead of div and use CSS for border or other style

```
<table> 
    <tr>
       <td>PRICE</td>
       <td>From XX to XX</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```